# Remove polygons within other polygons in a dataframe

Tags: geopandas

Given a dataframe, is it possible to find polygons that lie **within** another polygon in the same dataframe and remove them based on a condition?

For example, consider the following dataframe

```
                                            geometry          category            
0  POLYGON ((332294.432 2794730.319, 332294.032 2...            A                
1  POLYGON ((332193.232 2794730.719, 332192.832 2...            B                
2  POLYGON ((332271.632 2794731.519, 332271.232 2...            C                
3  POLYGON ((332271.632 2794731.519, 332271.232 2...            C
```

Suppose polygon 3 lies within polygon 2. Since they are both of category **C**, I would like to remove polygon 3. If they were of different categories, I would not do a removal.

Is there a way to do this within geopandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd
from itertools import permutations

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/within.shp')
category_field = 'cat'

indices = df.index.to_list()

to_delete = []
for p1, p2 in permutations(indices,2): #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list
    #print(p1, p2)
    if df.iloc[p1][category_field] == df.iloc[p2][category_field] and df.iloc[p1].geometry.within(df.iloc[p2].geometry):
        to_delete.append(p1)

#>>to_delete
#>>Out[18]: [1]

if len(to_delete)>0:
    df = df.drop(df.index[to_delete])
```

Comment: Can you please tell how did you access GeoPandas in QGIS?

Comment: I didnt. I did the coding in [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) and just displayed the polygons in QGIS

Comment: Thank you, I know that it is possible, but still can not achieve that ...

Comment: This seems like it could be extremely slow with a layer containing many features as the formula for permutations is P(n,r) = n! / (n-r)!. Maybe an intermediate step could be used to reduce n by comparing the distances from centroids to nearest neighboring centroids and filtering them with some threshold value.